# populate on focus with json and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i have one project in which i have to populate one list on the focus of input ...?
how can we populate it on focus and empty on blur ...please use javascript only

code is like:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="inp" />
<div id="populate"></div>
```

json:

```
var list = [
    { "name" :"abc" },
    { "name" :"abc" },
    { "name" :"abc" },
    { "name" :"abc" },
    { "name" :"abc" },
    { "name" :"abc" }
];
```

how can we populate it on focus and empty on blur ...please use javascript only

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in JavaScript, especially since you have your JSON data separate already, that is key.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="demo">
  <h2>List population</h2>
  <input>
  <select><option></option></select>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var mod = {
  view: function(state, props) {
    state.input = {
      _onblur: function() {
        state.option = []
      },
      _onfocus: function() {
        state.option = props.list.map(function(v) {
          return {
            _text: v.name
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the full working example: http://jsbin.com/toxopizopa/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var doc = document;
var inp = doc.getElementById('inp');
var div = doc.getElementById('populate');


inp.onfocus = function() {
    var ul = doc.createElement('ul');
    ul.id = 'ul';
    div.appendChild(ul);
    for (var k in list) {
        var li = doc.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = list[k].name;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

inp.onblur = function() {
    (elem = doc.getElementById('ul')).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Here's the jsbin https://jsbin.com/pakigezate/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#inp").on('focus',function(){
jQuery.map(list,function(k,v){
    $("#populate").append(v+'<br/>');     
  });
```

});

$("#inp").on('blur',function(){

```
$("#populate").html("");
```

});